# How can I send this type of string with api call

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, protocol-buffers, protocol-buffers-3

I am using protobuf and need to send converted bytes with api request, and need to decode again on server, string will be like this:

> \b\xC0\xB3\xB9\xDD\xFC\x1C\x12XBalance debited with 62.0 Expiry Date is 09-11-2016 09:10:00 Remaining Balance is 1490.0\x1A\x0FDebited Balance\"XBalance debited with 62.0 Expiry Date is 09-11-2016 09:10:00 Remaining Balance is 1490.0(\x99\x9C\xCE\xBF\x05

How can I send this type of the request and get properly on server?

Or anyone help me to send information using protobuf.

When I send string in body in then it replace form

```
\x99\x9C\xCE\xBF\x05
```

to

```
x99x9CxCExBFx05
```

and when send in headers it replaced like

```
\\x99\\x9C\\xCE\\xBF\\x05
```

Thanks

Comment: Whether you do want the exact same string on the server, use `base64`.

Comment: you mean need to encode this in base64 first then send to server and decode there?

Comment: I would go this way, yes. It’s the simplest and safest one.

Comment: @mudasobwa any other way to do this? with google protobuf?

Comment: after decoding with base64 it also produce the string with double backward slash like: 
\\b\\xC0\\xB3\\xB9\\xDD\\xFC\\x1C\\, it seems problem with ruby online encode decode seems working

Comment: “after decoding with base64 it also produce the string with double backward slash”—it does not. You mix up how ruby prints strings out. Try `original = '\x99\x9C\xCE\xBF\x05'; original == Base64.decode64(Base64.encode64(original))`. What you think are double quotes is in fact how ruby prints strings out. `puts original #⇒ \x99\x9C\xCE\xBF\x05`, but `p original #⇒ "\\x99\\x9C\\xCE\\xBF\\x05"`. Also, google the difference between single-quoted strings and double-quoted strings in ruby.

Comment: @mudasobwa, It seems problem with encoding when encoding using ruby for the same string it returns this: CMCzud38HBJYQmFsYW5jZSBkZWJpdGVkIHdpdGggNjIuMCBFeHBpcnkgRGF0\nZ...... and I can decode it as original as well and when  encode using online tool it return like XGJceEMwXHhCM1x4QjlceEREXHhGQ1x4MUNceDEyWEJhbGFu.....

Answer (score 0):

Besides what I have written in comments, the [ruby `protobuf` binding home](https://github.com/google/protobuf/tree/master/ruby#installation-from-gem) contains a perfect example of how it’s to be achieved:

```
require 'google/protobuf'

# generated from my_proto_types.proto with protoc:
#  $ protoc --ruby_out=. my_proto_types.proto
require 'my_proto_types'

mymessage = MyTestMessage.new(:field1 => 42, :field2 => ["a", "b", "c"])
mymessage.field1 = 43
mymessage.field2.push("d")
mymessage.field3 = SubMessage.new(:foo => 100)

# ⇓⇓⇓ HERE ⇓⇓⇓
encoded_data = MyTestMessage.encode(mymessage)
# ⇑⇑⇑ HERE ⇑⇑⇑
decoded = MyTestMessage.decode(encoded_data)
assert decoded == mymessage
```

Everything you need is to encode the bytes before sending:

```
mymessage = MyTestMessage.new(message: '\x99\x9C\xCE\xBF\x05')
encoded_data = MyTestMessage.encode(mymessage)
# OR encoded_data = MyTestMessage.encode_json(mymessage)
```

and now send `encoded_data` to your recipient.

Comment: Yes I see this example but string will be generated from android side and come to ruby with an api call thats why I have to send string

Comment: `MyTestMessage.encode(mymessage)` produces string, does not it?

Comment: yes it produce the string like I have added in my question also decoding is working but problem is that when I send the same string with api not able to receive the same on ruby side